# How to remove parent section in an attachment URL in wordpress?

Tags: php, urls

In wordpress, an unattached attachment URL is

```
http://domain.com/?attachment=$id
```

Once after it's attached to a parent, it goes with parent's URL structure, for example:

```
http://domain.com/parent-title/attachment-title
```

I need my attachments URL contains only root domain as the unattached ones. How to make it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [add a filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to the function that gets attachment links to force that format:

```
function wpa60888_attachment_link( $link, $id ){
    return home_url() . '/?attachment_id=' . $id;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpa60888_attachment_link', 10, 2 );
```

Calls to [`get_attachment_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link) will have this filter applied to the output.

Comment: This filter works only if site is under default permalink structure. If site use pretty permalink structure, it will go with the pretty ones.

Comment: Just figure out where I went wrong-- the file I add the above function was required if is_admin. Now I have the file loaded disregarding admin or not, the filter works. Thanks!